# Trouble getting the C# Equivalent from Vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, syntax

I've tried everything I can think of to get the equivalent c#, but I just can't figure out what is going on and I don't understand the syntax.

```
For Each c As Control In pnlThumbs.Controls
            If Not IsNothing(c.Tag) Then
                Dim GUID As String = CStr(CType(c.Tag, Object())(0))
            End If
 Next
```

The problem I'm having is getting the string `GUID` the same way in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use something like [Online converter](http://converter.telerik.com/). It would tell you that the equivalent code in C# is:

```
foreach (Control c in pnlThumbs.Controls) 
{
    if ((c.Tag != null)) 
    {
        string GUID = Convert.ToString((object[])c.Tag(0));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: It seems that Telerik converter failed this time. The correct answer can be found using another [online converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/):

```
foreach (Control c in pnlThumbs.Controls) 
{
    if ((c.Tag != null)) 
    {
        string GUID = Convert.ToString((object[])c.Tag[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, didnt event think to use a Online converter.

Comment: Still get an error on that though. Says Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `object'

Comment: Found it:
string GUID = ((object[])(c.Tag))[0].ToString();

Comment: @Dylan It seems converters cannot get it right every time, but at least they give the initial conversion that can be tweaked